# setting min-width for button control in CSS for BPM Coach.The button width should expand wrt text size as well

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, business-process-management, css

I tried to set the min-width for a button control in CSS for using it in BPM Coach.But failed.How can I set the min-width for button? and the size of the button should increase wrt the size of the text.

Answer (score 0):

try this inline css it will work.

```
<input type="button" style="width:50px;height:5em;min-width:40px;" />
```